# SigmaJS: is it possible to draw a data structure diagram?

Tags: sigma.js

I am looking with interest at SigmaJS.
I am wondering if it allows to render a data structure like in [GraphVIZ](https://graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/datastruct.html).

The concept is that edges are not created between nodes, but between a property of a node (or field) and another node.
The final intent is to draw a GraphQL model from a GraphQL schema, which is not entirely an ER model, but also not just a basic graph diagram.

I can't find any advice on the manual, probably because Graphology does not allow for it. Or maybe there's a trick I can't figure out.